# XC8 Compiler array of struct initialization problem

Tags: pic, mplab, mplabx, xc8

I'm using MPLAB X IDE with XC8 compiler and I would like to create a menu system to a GLCD module, but I'm having trouble initializing my `MainMenuItemsList[]` array. I'm not getting error on compliling but if I'm debugging the project, I can see that only the first item is initialized. What can be the cause?

Here is the relevant code fragment:

```
typedef struct menuitem
{
  char ItemName[10];
  void (*handler)(void);
  struct menu *ChildSubMenu;
}MenuItem;

typedef struct menu
{
  char MenuName[10];
  char NumberItems;
  //struct menu *ParentMenu;
  MenuItem *Items[12];
}Menu;

MenuItem MainMenuItemsList[12] = {  {"SubMenu1", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu2", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu3", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu4", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu5", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu6", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu7", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu8", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu9", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu10", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu11", NULL, NULL},
                                    {"SubMenu11", NULL, NULL}
                                };

Menu MainMenu = {"MainMenu",12,&MainMenuItemsList};
```

Comment: How do you know that the array is not being initialized correctly? Did you tested on an actual LCD? Some of the later versions of MPLAB X are not displaying the correct values on the watch window.

Comment: Yes I've tested it. The strings "MainMenu" and "SubMenu1" are written correctly on the LCD but the other arrays ItemName[10] are full of null characters instead of SubMenu2...11. (By the way I'm using MPLAB X v2.15)

Comment: It wont function because I need a list of structs, from that I select the first member and write the name of it (SubMenu1) to the screen than I choose the second element etc. That appears in my code like this:
`void drawMenu(Menu *menuToShow, unsigned char selectedIndex)
{
   ...
   glcd_puts(menuToShow->Items[i]->ItemName,8,i+1,0,1,-2);
   ...
}`

And the call of the function:

`drawMenu(&MainMenu, 0);`
Sorry but I don't know how to format the code block properly, but I tried it for several times.

Comment: Does nobody have an idea? I've tried this too, but it didn't worked. [link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96847/pic-xc8-compiler-array-of-structs?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you define `MenuItem *Items[12];` you are creating an array of addresses, not an address to an array of structs (which is what you want).

take the "[12]" out:

```
typedef struct menu
{
  char MenuName[10];
  char NumberItems;
  MenuItem * Items;
}Menu;
```